# Чтение .xml файла из файла ресурсов .resx

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

Создал файл ресурсов .resx, затем добавил в него уже существующий .xml файл. Теперь непонятно как как считать этот .xml файл из файла ресурсов .resx.

P.S. При чтении этого же .xml файла из файловой системы проблем не возникало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создавали ресурс стандартным образом, через свойства проекта?

[image: ResX Editor]

Тогда к ресурсу можно получить доступ просто по имени (у меня это `TestXml`):

```
var content = Properties.Resources.TestXml;
var doc = XDocument.Parse(content);
Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

Программа выдаёт:

```
<root>
  <test />
</root>
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо.

Comment: @Corax: Пожалуйста!